# send a string with serialized data in django views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**views.py**

```
def get(self , request , format=None):
                current_timestamp = time.time()
                products = GrProduct.objects.raw(('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id > 9 ')

                tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
                product_sync_ts = datetime.now(tz)
                product_sync_ts_iso = product_sync_ts.isoformat()
                content = json.dumps(product_sync_ts_iso)

                print content

                if products:
                    serializer = ProductSerializer(
                        content,
                        products,many=True
                    )
                    raise APIException200(request, serializer.data)
                else:
                    content = {'details': "No such product exists"}
                    raise APIException400(request, content)
```

I am trying to send the current time stamp in a specific format along with the serialised data. But it doesn't work this way. Can anyone help me in solving this problem? I am working on drf and django.

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by "it doesn't work this way"?

Comment: it doesn't work the way i have sent the content variable in serializer object.. I know this is wrong way..but I dont know correct way either

Comment: Can you post what output you are getting and which is the expected one?

Comment: You should really avoid using raw queries, especially for something that simple. And it's not clear what's not working, so we can't help you until that is cleared up.